# Change contents of mustache based on variable

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to change the contents of a mustache based on something else?

I have 3 different arrays and based on which one is "selected" I'd like to change the `v-for` loop (different key-names in the various arrays).

```
<template>
    <select>
        <option v-for="item in list" :value="item._id">{{ getList(value) }}
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
                value: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getList: function(value) {
            if (value === 0) {
                var new_value = "item.name";
                return new_value; } 
            else {
                var new_value = "item.name2";
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: `value` is set somewhere else.

But, of course this only returns the string and so the value of `new_value` ends up being the value for all the options.

Sorry, I'm a real newbie and I'm in over my head...

Comment: 1. Place your whole code (you are using in a problem) that is connected to the subject. All of it, so we have wider perspective. 2. If you can reproduce the trouble using codepen or something like that.

Comment: I've been yelled at for posting all my code here before - so I figured I'd make it as brief as possible ... All of it is here --> https://codepen.io/jogyth/pen/jONXqvL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass both `item` and `value` to `getList`:

```html
{{ getList(item, value) }}
```

Then you can return the relevant name directly:

```js
getList: function(item, value) {
    if (value === 0) {
        return item.name;
    }
    else {
        return item.name2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's it. Now, why did I not think about that? Thanks a bunch @skirtle.